# Understanding a reference to Corpus Inscriptionum Latinarum

Tags: inscription, reference-request, corpus-inscriptionum-latinarum

On page 33 of [Companion Animals & Us](https://books.google.pt/books?id=tSs2yV_F4n0C&printsec=frontcover&dq=Companion+Animals+%26+US&hl=en&sa=X&ei=r4OYU8jDJ6_50gWrwoDICg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false), there is a line:

> I am in tears, while carrying you to your last resting place as much as I rejoiced when bringing you home in my own hands fifteen years ago.

It cites *Corpus Inscriptionum Latinarum 10.659.1-2* as its source.

I looked at [entry 659 in Corpus Inscriptionum Latinarum X](https://arachne.uni-koeln.de/arachne/index.php?view[layout]=buchseite_item&search[constraints][buchseite][PS_BuchseiteID]=891370&view[section]=uebersicht&view[page]=0) and found an inscription that did not match the one one cited in *Companion Animals & Us,* namely:

> ioui optumo maximo | pro salute m. aurelI antonini aug | s. populusq. aquinas

I would like to find the inscription referenced in *Corpus Inscriptionum Latinarum.* What have I misunderstood?

[Here](https://cil.bbaw.de/cil_en/dateien/index.php?id=10) are links to the other books.

Comment: Try searching [here](http://www.manfredclauss.de/gb/index.html).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I haven't completely figured out the book's layout, but it appears that it contains both volumes IX and X. In any case, the numbering starts over at index #160 (pg. 4), and the entry you're looking for is at [index #230 (pg. 74)](https://arachne.uni-koeln.de/arachne/index.php?view[layout]=buchseite_item&search[constraints][buchseite][PS_BuchseiteID]=891498&view[section]=uebersicht&view[page]=0):

[image]

> Portavi lacrimis madidus te nostra catella,
>  quod feci lustris
>   laetior ante tribus.
>  Ergo mihi, Patrice, iam non dabis oscula
>   mille
>  nec poteris collo grata cubare meo.
>  Tristis marmorea
>   posui te sede merentem
>  et iunxi semper manib(us) ipse meis,
>   morib(us) argutis hominem simulare paratam;
>  perdidimus quales,
>   hei mihi, delicias.
>  Tu dulcis, Patrice, nostras attingere
>   mensas
>  consueras, gremio poscere blanda cibos.
>  Lambere tu
>   calicem lingua rapiente solebas
>  quem tibi saepe meae sustinuere
>   manus,
>  accipere et lassum cauda gaudente frequenter
>  (final
>   line missing)

I came across the following [translation](http://thelatinreadingblog.blogspot.com/2016/04/how-sweet-was-my-dog.html):

> Bedewed with tears I have carried you, our little dog, as in happier
>   circumstances I did fifteen years ago. So now, Patrice, you will no
>   longer give me a thousand kisses, nor will you be able to lie
>   affectionately round my neck. You were a good dog, and in sorrow I
>   have placed you in a marble tomb, and I have united you forever to
>   myself when I die. You readily matched a human with your clever ways;
>   alas, what a pet we have lost! You, sweet Patrice, were in the habit
>   of joining us at table and fawningly asking for food in our lap, you
>   were accustomed to lick with your gready tongue the cup which my hands
>   often held for you and regularly to welcome your tired master with
>   wagging tail . . . . . . (E. Courtney (1995))

Comment: spot on!.......