# Why was ante tribus translated as "fifteen years ago"?

Tags: latin-to-english-translation, translation-explanation, numbers, time

In an answer I posted [here](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/7701/81), I provided someone else's translation which translated *ante tribus* as "fifteen years ago". The translation provided in the question also translated *tribus* the same way:

> Portavi lacrimis madidus te nostra catella,
>  quod feci lustris
>   laetior **ante tribus**.

Is that correct? Why would it be fifteen years and not three?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

*Lustrum* has several meanings, but that which applies here is the period of five years which elapsed from census to census. The phrase is actually *lustris ante tribus*, or 'three lustra ago'.

A good dictionary will give further explanation, if you require it.

Comment: Word order in Latin is insane, isn't it :-)